How to solve Lexicographically smallest permutation using adjacent swaps?
What should be the approach of solve the below problem? Can't find a way to solve it.

Given an array of integers, find the lexicographically smallest permutation of this array that you can produce by swapping each pair of adjacent elements exactly once.
For example, if the array is [5, 4, 1, 3, 2], then the answer is [1, 5, 2, 4, 3], which can be produced with this sequence of swaps:

[5, 4, 1, 3, 2] → [5, 1, 4, 3, 2]
[5, 1, 4, 3, 2] → [1, 5, 4, 3, 2]
[1, 5, 4, 3, 2] → [1, 5, 4, 2, 3]
[1, 5, 4, 2, 3] → [1, 5, 2, 4, 3]

Note that the sequence includes exactly one swap at each position: the elements at indices 0 and 1 are swapped exactly once, the elements at indices 1 and 2 are swapped exactly once, etc.


That's an interesting problem! What's your question about it?

@TedLyngmo yes lexographically smallest given the conditions of max one swap per index with its right.
ruakh need help solving the problem and understanding the approach.

"max one swap" or "exactly once", which one is it?

Exactly one operation for each index.

It seems you can use a greedy approach:

Locate the least value in the array after its first element: let its index be 
Perform the swaps necessary to bring that value to index 0. So swap the pairs at (−1,), (−2,−1), ... until index 0 is reached, getting the least value that was found in the previous step.
If  is not the last index of the array, then consider the subarray from index  up to its end, and repeat the above procedure for that subarray.

To avoid a O(²) complexity you could perform a preprocessing step where you register for each index  which is the index  that has the least value in the partition from index +1 to the end of the array.
This way the first bullet point in the above procedure can be a simple lookup in O(1) time.
Here is an implementation in JavaScript:


function solve(arr) {
    // For each index "i" find the index "j" that has the least value 
    //   in the partition that starts after index "i".
    let j = arr.length - 1;
    const next = Array(arr.length - 1);
    for (let i = arr.length - 2; i >= 0; i--) {
        next[i] = j;
        if (arr[i] <= arr[j]) j = i;
    }
    // Main algorithm
    let i = 0;
    while (i < arr.length - 1) {
        const j = next[i]; // arr[j] has least value at the right of index i
        // Perform rotation (swaps)
        const least = arr[j];
        for (let k = j - 1; k >= i; k--) {
            arr[k+1] = arr[k];
        }
        arr[i] = least;
        i = j;
    }
}

// Example run
const arr = [5, 4, 1, 3, 2];
solve(arr);
console.log(arr);




That pre-processing with the lookup table is very nice! It requires some memory, but for large arrays, it may pay off in less time spent looking for the next smallest value in the range that is after i. +1 - Fwiw, I made an implementation of the naive way to search for the next smallest after having moved the smallest left. :) naive implementation

Least element might not necessarily lead to best result. Say in case of arr
[8,9,1,10,2,3,4,5,6,7]. Lexographically smallest would be to shift 10 instead of 1 to the first element

@sharin, you use a different interpretation of lexicographic order where you convert numbers to their string representation in decimal(!) notation and then consider the concatenated string. I did not take that interpretation here, but followed how tuple comparison works in Python, which is said to be lexicographical. This is in line with what Wikipedia has for its definition: "a generalization [...] to sequences of [...] elements of a totally ordered set." (the set of numbers here).

@sharingan What order would you say is lexicographically less than 1,8,2,9,3,4,5,6,7,10 (using the same restrictions) that both tincot's and my algorithm result in? There is no interpretation of your question that would lead us to think in terms of string concatenation.

@TedLyngmo What result does yours give for that? (Can't try it myself, godbolt's shitty UI doesn't let me edit or copy.)

@nocomment Exactly the same as trincot's solution: 1,8,2,9,3,4,5,6,7,10. There is no difference in trincot's and my base algorithms, only trincot's is optimized for speed when the arrays are large and mine does not use any extra memory and has to do repeated searches, which will probably be noticable with large arrays.

@TedLyngmo That's a wrong result, and not what trincot produces. And did you actually test yours with it?

@nocomment Yes I tested it with both. trincots gives: [1, 8, 2, 9, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 10] mine gives 1 8 2 9 3 4 5 6 7 10 - I can't spot any difference. What is the correct result according to you?

@TedLyngmo Ah, sorry, I meant with [1,8,2,9,3,4,5,6,7,10] as input. (Didn't realize it was the output for an input mentioned earlier). I managed to download yours now, and as I expected, it goes into an infinite loop with that.

@nocomment Aha, yeah, it seems I didn't bugcheck my comment thoughrougly :-) The algorithm I had in my mind is most probably correct - I just failed implementing it :-) It's easily solved with some duct tape in form of an early exit (and then it gives the same result as tricont's), but then I'd rather rework it to not have such shenanigans.

@MattTimmermans Does that have an advantage?

@MattTimmermans I'm curious too. Doesn't trincot's preprocessing do exactly that?

@nocomment Ha.  Actually no.  I was thinking about that step incorrectly.  Trincot did it right.

There were a few gotchas i had to debug, so I added some helpful debug printouts.
The algorithm used is the same as discussed - i.e. Move the lowest on the rightby swapping then consider only from where it was swapped from.
I recalculate an array of the min indices to the right after a group of swaps; and only re-calculate for the positions to the right.
The code
# %%
from itertools import repeat


def min_perm_for_single_swaps(values: list[int | float], debug=False):
    if debug:
        print(f"\n\nDBG: {values = }")
        
    count = len(values)

    index_from_left = 0
    answer = values[::]
    min_right_index =  gen_min_indices(answer)
    swaps = []

    while index_from_left < count:
        i_swap = False
        swap_to = min_right_index[index_from_left]
        if swap_to > index_from_left:
            i_swap = True
            for j in range(swap_to, index_from_left, -1):
                one_swap(answer, j, swaps)
            index_from_left = swap_to
            min_right_index[index_from_left:] =  gen_min_indices(answer[index_from_left:],
                                                                 index_from_left)
        else:
            index_from_left += 1
        if debug and i_swap:
            print(f"DBG:       -> {answer[:swap_to+1]}+{answer[swap_to+1:]}, {swaps = }")
            if len(swaps) != len(set(swaps)):
                print("Error: duplicate column swaps")
 
    if debug:
        print()
   
    return answer


def one_swap(lst: list, a: int, swaps_so_far: list[tuple[int, int]]) -> None:
    "swap lst[a] and lst[a-1], in-place. append (a, a-1) to swaps_so_far"
    lst[a], lst[a-1] = lst[a-1], lst[a]
    swaps_so_far.append((a, a-1))
    
    
def gen_min_indices(values: list, offset: int=0):
    "indices of minimum value of sublist to the right"
    count = len(values)
    right_min = values[-1]
    mn_right_index = [count - 1] * count
    for i in range(count - 1, -1, -1):
        if (this := values[i]) < right_min:
            right_min = this
            mn_right_index[0: i+1] = repeat(i, i+1)
    return [x + offset for x in mn_right_index]


print(f"SO: {min_perm_for_single_swaps([5, 4, 1, 3, 2], debug=True) = }")

# %%

print(f"SO: {min_perm_for_single_swaps( [1,8,2,9,3,4,5,6,7,10], debug=True) = }")

# %%

print(f"SO: {min_perm_for_single_swaps( [8,9,1,10,2,3,4,5,6,7], debug=True) = }")


The output

DBG: values = [5, 4, 1, 3, 2]
DBG:       -> [1, 5, 4]+[3, 2], swaps = [(2, 1), (1, 0)]
DBG:       -> [1, 5, 2, 4, 3]+[], swaps = [(2, 1), (1, 0), (4, 3), (3, 2)]

SO: min_perm_for_single_swaps([5, 4, 1, 3, 2], debug=True) = [1, 5, 2, 4, 3]


DBG: values = [1, 8, 2, 9, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 10]
DBG:       -> [1, 2, 8]+[9, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 10], swaps = [(2, 1)]
DBG:       -> [1, 2, 3, 8, 9]+[4, 5, 6, 7, 10], swaps = [(2, 1), (4, 3), (3, 2)]
DBG:       -> [1, 2, 3, 8, 4, 9]+[5, 6, 7, 10], swaps = [(2, 1), (4, 3), (3, 2), (5, 4)]
DBG:       -> [1, 2, 3, 8, 4, 5, 9]+[6, 7, 10], swaps = [(2, 1), (4, 3), (3, 2), (5, 4), (6, 5)]
DBG:       -> [1, 2, 3, 8, 4, 5, 6, 9]+[7, 10], swaps = [(2, 1), (4, 3), (3, 2), (5, 4), (6, 5), (7, 6)]
DBG:       -> [1, 2, 3, 8, 4, 5, 6, 7, 9]+[10], swaps = [(2, 1), (4, 3), (3, 2), (5, 4), (6, 5), (7, 6), (8, 7)]

SO: min_perm_for_single_swaps( [1,8,2,9,3,4,5,6,7,10], debug=True) = [1, 2, 3, 8, 4, 5, 6, 7, 9, 10]


DBG: values = [8, 9, 1, 10, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
DBG:       -> [1, 8, 9]+[10, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7], swaps = [(2, 1), (1, 0)]
DBG:       -> [1, 8, 2, 9, 10]+[3, 4, 5, 6, 7], swaps = [(2, 1), (1, 0), (4, 3), (3, 2)]
DBG:       -> [1, 8, 2, 9, 3, 10]+[4, 5, 6, 7], swaps = [(2, 1), (1, 0), (4, 3), (3, 2), (5, 4)]
DBG:       -> [1, 8, 2, 9, 3, 4, 10]+[5, 6, 7], swaps = [(2, 1), (1, 0), (4, 3), (3, 2), (5, 4), (6, 5)]
DBG:       -> [1, 8, 2, 9, 3, 4, 5, 10]+[6, 7], swaps = [(2, 1), (1, 0), (4, 3), (3, 2), (5, 4), (6, 5), (7, 6)]
DBG:       -> [1, 8, 2, 9, 3, 4, 5, 6, 10]+[7], swaps = [(2, 1), (1, 0), (4, 3), (3, 2), (5, 4), (6, 5), (7, 6), (8, 7)]
DBG:       -> [1, 8, 2, 9, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 10]+[], swaps = [(2, 1), (1, 0), (4, 3), (3, 2), (5, 4), (6, 5), (7, 6), (8, 7), (9, 8)]

SO: min_perm_for_single_swaps( [8,9,1,10,2,3,4,5,6,7], debug=True) = [1, 8, 2, 9, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 10]

